# jQuery Increase image size without disrupting layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have two lists of images for a before and after section. How can i use jquery to increase the size of an image that is clicked without disrupting the layout of the other images.

```
<div id="concept-reality-wrapper">
    <div class="col-1">

        <h2>Concept</h2>

        <ul>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-2">

        <h2>Reality</h2>

        <ul>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="image.jpg" /> </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the css modifier `z-index` this could be helpful in that you could pull an image above the rest in terms of its render level. There are however caveats to this method.

Comment: is your image size always the same before you increase the size? then you could just put them into a div with fixed size, and the img will overflow the div and not change the layout. or you could just give the <li> a fixed size, that should work too. also: make your example in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/), its very useful for us to help you

Answer (score 1):

Do it [with CSS only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform#scale)..you can see how it's done in my gallery:
http://dropthebit.com/demos/photobox/

Basically you just use `transform:scale()` and that doesn't effect anything but scales the thing.

Comment: i've deleted my answer ok :-) and sorry